Two scripts (Python and VBA) with the same logic produce different results when regex is implemented
I've created two scripts: one in Python and the other in VBA. Both scripts do the same thing but produce different results.
I've used a few links within the scripts to scrape a Facebook link from the page source, implementing regex. Most importantly, I used the same pattern within the scripts to avoid the variation of results, but sadly, the significant variation of results is noticed.
Python script with results:
import re
import requests

links = [
    'https://fairmontdental.ca/',
    'https://northview-dental.com/',
    'http://northlanddental.com/',
    'http://cosmodentallondon.ca/',
]

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:124.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/124.0',
}

for link in links:
    response = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
    webpage_content = response.text
    pattern = r'<a\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?href=[\'"](https?://(?:www\.)?facebook\.com/[^\'"]*)[\'"][^>]*?>'
    try:
        fblink = re.findall(pattern, webpage_content)[0]
    except IndexError: fblink = ""
    print((link,fblink))

Output:
('https://fairmontdental.ca/', 'https://www.facebook.com/Fairmont-Dental-Centre-105718408446937/')
('https://northview-dental.com/', 'https://www.facebook.com/northviewdentalcentre/')
('http://northlanddental.com/', 'https://www.facebook.com/Northland-Dental-Centre-134147169935714/')
('http://cosmodentallondon.ca/', 'https://www.facebook.com/CosmoDentalCentre')

VBA script with results:
Sub FetchFbLink()
    Dim links As Variant, regEx As Object, Ohttp As Object, match As Object
    Dim text As String, FBlink$, i As Integer

    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Set Ohttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    links = Array( _
        "https://northview-dental.com/", _
        "http://northlanddental.com/", _
        "http://cosmodentallondon.ca/", _
        "https://fairmontdental.ca/" _
    )
    For i = LBound(links) To UBound(links)
        
        With Ohttp
            .Open "GET", links(i), False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
            On Error Resume Next
            .send
            text = .responseText
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
        
        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .Pattern = "<a\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?href=[\'""]((https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?facebook\.com\/[^\'""]*)[\'""][^>]*?>"
        End With
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Set match = regEx.Execute(text)(0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If Not match Is Nothing Then
            FBlink = match.SubMatches(0)
        Else
            FBlink = ""
        End If
    
        Debug.Print links(i), FBlink
        Set match = Nothing
    Next i
End Sub

Output:
https://northview-dental.com/  https://www.facebook.com/northviewdentalcentre/
http://northlanddental.com/ 
http://cosmodentallondon.ca/              
https://fairmontdental.ca/  

How can I achieve the same results in VBA?

Have you compared the raw page content before you applied the regexes on it?

Unfortunately, I didn't, but I guess the page content is different, hence the different results. Can I do anything to fix the VBA script in order to have the same page content so the regex doesn't fail to grab the desired results?

Then you should compare the raw content to find out if the request or the regex is the cause of the difference. One thing I see is that the user agent of the requests is different.
